# How to test user has claims after _signInManager.SignInWithClaimsAsync is called in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, integration-testing

I want to test that user has assigned claims after it is logged in.
I made integration tests and I realized that `httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` is true only after response is set to client (`Set-Cookie` header is sent)
So my idea was to get that cookie and send another request. That works but how do I get claims? My ideas was to get it using `_appFactory.Services.GetRequuiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>()` but `HttpContext` property of that service is always `null`.

Here is code to make it even more clear:

```
   //Arrange
      var httpClient = _appFactory.CreateClient();
      var signInManager = _appFactory.Services.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<User>>();
    var userManager = _appFactory.Services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<User>>();
    var authService = _appFactory.Services.GetRequiredService<IAuthService>();

     **var httpContextAccessor= _appFactory.Services.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();**
   
    var controller = new AuthController(signInManager, userManager, authService);
    var aspNetCookieName = ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application";
    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext()
    {
        RequestServices = _appFactory.Services,

    };

    controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = httpContext;
    signInManager.Context = httpContext;

    //Act

    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/users"); //first request
    HttpResponseMessage responseHomePageBeforeLogin = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

    _ = await controller.Login(new Models.ViewModel.LoginViewModel()
    {
        Email = TestsConstants.DEFAULT_USER.Email,
        Password = TestsConstants.DEFAULT_USER.Password
    });

    _ = controller.Response.Headers.TryGetValue("Set-Cookie", out StringValues value);
    var cookie = value.FirstOrDefault();
    requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "/users");
    requestMessage.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookie);
    HttpResponseMessage responseHomePage = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

  **var httpContext=httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;//here is null httpContext**
    //Assert
  Assert.IsNotNull(responseHomePage);
        Assert.AreEqual("/users", responseHomePage!.RequestMessage!.RequestUri!.LocalPath);
        Assert.IsNotNull(value);
        Assert.IsTrue(value.FirstOrDefault()!.Contains(aspNetCookieName));
```

Comment: I am struggling with this now too. Let me know if you find out something. My post is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72664308/c-sharp-integration-test-system-invalidoperationexception-httpcontext-must-not